# How to migrate a .NET Windows Service application to Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows-services, cross-platform

What is the best approach to migrate window service built in C#.net to a linux non .net base.
What language will best suited for the task?
what are the issues that can rise?
and if the window service uses much I/O operation what should the optimal solution for that. technologically wise and dependency wise.?

Answer (score 1):

What about C#: Have you considered using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?

Java shares much *syntax* with C#, so that's not the hard part. You have to consider all the *frameworks/libraries* etc. Mono does provide a lot of compatible libraries.